# How create similar code in a project

Tags: java, eclipse, opennlp, uima, cleartk

I have a java project that uses [cleartk](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/). Now I need to make an extra code to it and test. Under their project/src/main/java/org.cleartk.syntax.opennlp/ already have some java file. I need to duplicate one of them, rename and change the code inside, meaning that I need to create some thing with same format but different function (the one I gonna make, they call it an annotator). Each of this java file will link with some class (in target folder), so is there anyway to copy and create all related file, class so that I can make change in all of them ? I am using Eclipse, and dont know whether there is such a method ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try their [Developer pages](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/wiki/DeveloperSetup) and [Developer FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/wiki/DeveloperFAQ)?